# C#: Force constructor signature using abstract class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, constructor, abstract

I've been searching for a while on this because I'm naturally forgetful and I thought it would be nice to build something (an abstract class, interface, etc.?) that would force me to implement certain bits of code in a class I was writing.

In particular, I would like to force a new class to always have a constructor that takes a single parameter typed as itself in order to make duplication of the object easier.  I've seen articles/questions elsewhere that talk about this, but I'm not sure this particular question has been asked (at least that I can find) or I'm simply not understanding enough of the other articles/questions to realize it.  My apologies in advance.

I'm not interested in having a constructor in an abstract class, interface, etc. actually do anything.  I'm merely interested in defining the requirement for a constructor signature in a derived class.

My ideal class would look like this:

```
public class GoodClass
{
    public GoodClass(GoodClass goodClass)
    {
        // copy components of goodClass to this instance
    }
}
```

So, I first began researching interfaces and also started reading up on abstract classes.  I was thinking something like the code below would work, but alas I get errors.  Is what I'm trying to do even possible?  Is there any other way I could accomplish my goal without putting a sticky note on my monitor? :)

```
abstract class SelfConstructor
{
    abstract public SelfConstructor(SelfConstructor) { }
}

class NewClass : SelfConstructor
{
    //Required by SelfConstructor:
    public NewClass(NewClass newClass)
    {
        // copy components of newClass to this instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a ReSharper plugin that recognises this case and highlights the class if it doesn't have a "copy constructor". This would be a [daemon stage](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/2.04+Daemons+and+Daemon+Stages+%28R8%29) that would process the file as it's being edited, and add highlights. You can look through the abstract syntax tree of the file, look for all instances of `IConstructorDeclaration`, and then get the constructor's parameters from the `ParameterDeclarations` property. You can check that there is a constructor that only has one parameter, and that parameter is the same type as the class it's declared in.

You can compare the types by getting the constructor's parameter's `TypeUsage` and trying to downcast to `IUserTypeUsage`. You can then use `ScalarTypeName.Reference.Resolve()` to get an instance of `IDeclaredElement`. Compare this against the class's `IClassDeclaration.DeclaredElement` to see if they're the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, what you are talking about is a *copy constructor*, you actually get one by default!

C# doesn't have that concept (though of course you can define one); however, it is easier (and preferred) to simply implement `ICloneable` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)), which requires you to implement the `Clone` method, that does the same thing.

Instead of:

```
object myObj = new CloneableObject(otherObj);
```

You write:

```
object myObj = otherObj.Clone();
```

The other thing you *could* do is force a constructor signature by not having a default:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    //No abstract constructors!
    public BaseClass(BaseClass copy)
    {
    }
}
```

Now when you derive, you have to use that overload in the constructor. Nothing will force the *derived* signature, but at least you have to explicitly use it:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass() : base(this)
    {
    }
}
```

The above example clearly shows that it doesn't "force" you to have a copy constructor, but like a sticky note, would serve as a good reminder.

I would definitely go the interface route, as that is what is there for (and you can use an abstract implementation!).

Note that you can take advantage of `Object.MemberwiseClone` if you want a *shallow* copy for free. All objects get this, no interface required.

Comment: A clone method is fine, but actually Microsoft advises against implementing `ICloneable`, mainly due to the fact that the interface doesn't state anywhere if the clone is deep or shallow.

Comment: @AdiLester Thats completely true, `Clone` can do whatever you want. If you follow the semantic though, its basically an interface for a copy operation.

Comment: ... and here the quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Because callers of Clone cannot depend on the method performing a predictable cloning operation, we recommend that ICloneable not be implemented in public APIs."

Comment: You could of course, create `IDeepCloneable` or whatever you want to make the semantic clearer. If its just for me though, I'll stick with `ICloneable`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @BradleyDotNET.  Is there any benefit to using `ICloneable` other than being forced to implement `Clone()`?

Comment: @Hossy Probably not, unless you want to use a framework method that takes an `ICloneable` its mostly just a convenient interface